# subtract last two rows and write result to new table MySQL

Tags: php, python, mysql

Hi I have try to follow couple of examples how to solve my problem but with no success.

So here is the situation

I have a table with the following ( the table will increase with each month)

```
mysql> DESCRIBE poraba;
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| mesec      | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| voda_mrzla | varchar(5) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| voda_topla | varchar(5) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

With the following vaules

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM poraba;
+---------------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| mesec               | voda_mrzla | voda_topla | id_poraba |
+---------------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-03-03 16:19:08 | 5985       | 3417       |         1 |
| 2014-04-03 20:57:51 | 5978       | 3412       |         2 |
```

I would like to perform the following. Always only on last entry. So I get the difference between current and previous month.

Eg.:

```
voda_mrzla (from 2014-04-03) - voda_mrzla (from 2014-03-03) = difference_cold
voda_topla (from 2014-04-03) - voda_topla (from 2014-03-03) = difference_hot
```

in to

```
mysql> DESCRIBE usage_per_month;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| difference_cold | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| difference_hot  | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like poor database design. You should at least have an id column with an incremental value as a key. That way the (nonetheless cumbersome) query would be a little easier. Given your current design, what you need to do is this (very, very slow and inefficient):

```
insert into usage_per_month
select a.voda_mrzla - b.voda_mrzla, a.voda_topla - voda_topla
from ( select * from poraba where mesec = ( select max(mesec) from poraba) ) as a,
( select * from poraba where mesec = ( select max(mesec) from poraba where mesec <> (select max(mesec) from poraba) ) ) as b;
```

Yes, it's this ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing all "varchar" in to "int" adding ID to all tables and executing the following solved my problem

```
INSERT INTO usage_per_month (difference_cold, difference_hot) 
SELECT p1.voda_mrzla - p2.voda_mrzla AS poraba_mrzla1, p1.voda_topla - p2.voda_topla AS poraba_topla1 FROM poraba p1
  LEFT JOIN poraba p2 ON p2.`id_poraba` = (
    SELECT MAX(`id_poraba`) FROM poraba p3 WHERE p3.`id_poraba` < p1.`id_poraba`
  ) ORDER BY p1.id_poraba DESC LIMIT 1
```

Tnx for help!